# PHP: Calling a function within a return string

Tags: php, string, function, call

I'm trying to call a function within a string return statement. Both are in the same class. However, I'm obviously not calling it right because it doesn't work :)

```
private static function doSomething(){
   $d['dt'] = //unix time stamp here;

   return '<div class="date" title="Commented on '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.time_since($d['dt']).'</div>';
}

function time_since(){
   //return 'string';
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are calling time_since() and your function is time_stamp().

Second, in PHP you need to explicitly call it like $this->time_stamp() - it does not resolve it to object scope like C++ does.

Third, you cannot call a regular method from the static function because the object is not instantiated - make time_stamp() static too. If you do this, it needs to be invoked like self::time_stamp().

Comment: Sorry, I time_stamp was a typo. So, I've got it like this now, to no avail. (These are just examples instead of typing out all the code)

    private static function doSomething(){
       $d['dt'] = //unix time stamp here;

       return '<div class="date" title="Commented on '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.self::time_since($d['dt']).'</div>';
    }

    public static function time_stamp($time){
       //do stuff with the received string
       return 'new time string';
    }

Answer (score -1):

Is the code meant to use `time_since()` when the other method you have listed is `time_stamp()`?

Comment: This should have been a comment not an answer.